# How to improve vs2010 compile speed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Thanks first.
I'm studing nopcommerce, which the webiste project i need to compile reference 58 other projects.
so when i complie the website, the other 58 project also compiles again even i didn't change anyting in the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which projects will build in the Configuration Manager screen (Build -> Configuration Manager). Use this to select only the projects you intend to work on. Next time you Build Solution, the deselected projects not build and will report as 'Skipped' in the Build Output.

If you later need to build a project that you have deslected, you can right-click that project in the Solution Explorer and click "Build" to build just that project.

Comment: This can get confusing if you forget that you've deselected some projects and you modify their code, so if you go this route, you might want to consider creating a new configuration to work with for the reduced build. It's also worth noting, that unless you 'unload' the other projects you don't get the same memory usage benefits that a reduced solution size offers (I think this is more of an issue if you're using addins like resharper).

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* need to have all of the other projects in the same solution?

Usually there is a way of partitioning the projects so that groups of them, that are relevant to each other, are in smaller solutions.

If you're only changing the top level website project (which from your description may be the case), then you might be better off having another solution that only has that website project it in.  Rather than having project level references in your website project, you can have binary ones (which point at the assemblies output from the other projects).  That way, when you make changes to the website project, it doesn't have to go and check all of the dependencies to make sure that they're all up to date.

Idealy, you would restructure the projects in a way that creates sensible divisions, which will depend on what your 58 projects are responsible for.  You also may need to change some of your working/build/release practices to make sure that all of the right binaries are being built and referenced when you do development/releases but this is the sort of approach that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I undo reference of most of the projects, and instead with referecing the binary of the project, and it's fast now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010 you need super machine that was not yet developed. Especially if you are working with C++ projects. C# compiler is more optimized. I was thinking some time ago if would be possible something like using old compiler (VS 2005 or VS 2008) with new IDE that would be cool.

Comment: In one of our projects I measured compile time 1.8 times higher than in VS 2005 (8 minutes instead of 4.5 minutes).